# Completely unable to lazy load images on jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

I'm currently attempting to use the Lazy Load XT plugin in my jQuery Mobile site so as to reduce the waiting time needed to load a page that contains a lot of images.

The images are located on the '#mainPage' page which is my default jQuery Mobile page.

I use 'pageinit' to load images from the server and insert them into the page, as shown below:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainPage", function() { loadMain(); // Function retrieves images via ajax & inserts them into the '#main-content' div which is a <div> within '#mainPage'
});
```

Here is my '#mainPage' page structure:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="imagesContent masonry" id="main-content">
        </div>

        <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" href="#" id="more">More</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's the basic procedure I used to insert images and associated data  into '#main-content":

```
$.post(imagesDataURL, function(imagesData) {

        /*
        Handled Errors here
        */

        $('#main-content').append(imagesData); 
        hideLoading(); // Hide the Loading spinner

        }); // End of $.post
```

)

However my problem is that if I go directly to the URL: http://foo.com (with '#mainPage' being the default page shown to the visitor, and '#main-content' being a div within '#mainPage'), the Lazy Loading XT plugin does not work  and none of the images are shown, but if I click-through to the page (#mainPage) from any page on the site, the #mainPage images lazy load **perfectly**.

I tried the basic usage method advised by the 'Lazy Load XT' plugin author, described on: 
https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt, namely changing the 'src' attribute of the 'img' tag to 'data-src' (), it didn't work.

I then disabled auto initialization of the plugin in favor of manual initialization, and tried:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#mainPage", function() {
$(this).find("img[data-src]").lazyLoadXT();
});
```

which didn't work, so I tried:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainPage", function() {
$(this).find("img[data-src]").lazyLoadXT();
});
```

which also didn't work, so finally I tried:

```
$(window).on('pageshow',  function() {
$(window).lazyLoadXT();
});
```

And various other variations on the above 3, all unsuccessful (they don't work when I visit the '#mainPage' page directly, but they DO work when I click through to the '#mainPage' page from another jQuery Mobile page).

I would really, **really** appreciate it if anyone could show me how to get the images to lazy load when a user visits the '#mainPage' page directly (rather than lazy loading only when a user clicks through or taps through to the '#mainPage' page from another page).

I've spent the past 8+ hours on this issue without making the slightest bit of progress, and I'm now at a total loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `$(window).lazyLoadXT();` right after you inserted images into the page, i.e. after `$('#main-content').append(imagesData);`.

Alternatively it is possible to combine both calls to single one: `$('#main-content').append(imagesData).find('img[data-src]').lazyLoadXT();`.

Comment: I am overwhelmingly grateful to you. It worked perfectly. Thank you, and I **sincerely** mean that, Thank you.